# ggplot2 - density (stat_density_2d) plot using numerical sum not count

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a dataset with 29 columns and 2500 rows resulting from a test. Three columns need to be represented on a plot, the first two are simple X, Y coordinate pairs representing actual X, Y positions on an image used in the test, the third is a response from the participants giving a simple yes or no answer (recorded as 1 and -1 respectively).

Each X, Y coordinate was used name times in the test, and I'm trying to get an overall bias for each point. The values can be found by a simple sum of the Y, N answers. My problem is that I can't plot the "sum" of the answers, only the density of the yes and no separately. I need to show the bias towards yes and no overall for each point, so having two plots or simply plotting the two sets of results on the same plot is on little value.

This is a suitable reproducible bit of code that has the same characteristics...  Much of my data seems in favour of the Y answer, but I want to 'see' whether this is related to the X, Y coordinate position (distance away from a separate fixed point).

the code below does a reasonable job of simulating the three main columns of interest...

```
my.data <- data.frame(x = (rep((1:5), 5)),
                      y = (rep((1:5), 5)), 
                      z = sample(c(rep(-1, 10), rep(1, 40))))
ggplot(data = my.data, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) + 
  xlim(-1, 6) + ylim(-01, 6) + 
  stat_density_2d(aes(alpha = "density", fill = "density"), 
                  geom = "polygon", size = 0.2, contour = T,
                  n = 300, h = 1.5, bins = 20, colour = "purple") + 
  geom_point(data = my.data, aes(x, y), colour = "blue", size = 1)
```

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated - I've been stuck on this for 3 weeks now.

Comment: better code   my.data<-data.frame(x=(sample((1:10),10)),y=(sample((1:10),10)),z=sample(c(rep(-1,10),rep(1,90))))
ggplot(data = my.data, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) + xlim(-2, 13) + ylim(-2, 13) + stat_density_2d(aes(alpha = "density", fill = "density"), geom = "polygon", size = 0.1, contour = T, n = 300, h = 5, bins = 20, colour = "purple") + geom_point(data = my.data, aes(x, y), colour = "blue", size = 1)

Comment: I'm confused about the code in the post vs the code in your comment. What's better about the code in the comment? Which do you want us to help debug?

Comment: looking at kde2d it seems I need an n x n matrix defining the density for each X,Y pair - I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I seem to be only getting what looks like a count of points at each X,Y coordinate location, but what I need is the sum of the Yes and No responses (recorded as 1 and 01 respectively, so if a certain X,Y coordinate had 10 Y responses and 100 N responses then the sum should be -90 - I want to see the contours reflect this whereas at the moment they only show how many responses as each X,Y point not the bias towards Yes or No.

Comment: Could you post an example of somewhere else that this was done? I'm just kinda confused, especially as far as how you would show negative values in order to convey a bias, in a density plot.

Comment: A simple part I can help with right now, though, is that you want `aes(fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..)` in your `stat_density_2d`. Right now you have density, but this actually calculates levels instead, and you have it in quotes, so `ggplot` will interpret that as just mapping the word "density" onto the fill

Comment: This is my problem, I haven't found anything, but this is what I need.  My idea was to have +ve contours of one colour and -ve of another. then where the result is 0 (which is actually the point of interest to me - equal pull, no bias) there would be no contour and no colour - a bit like sea level on a landmass contour map.

Comment: Thanks for the help there, I tried to use ..level.. before, and also seen some examples with ..density.. in the aesthetics.  ..level.. changes colours of the fill, and ..density.. returns an error.

Comment: I'm wondering whether there is a similar call that will use the sum of the values to apply to fill?  Perhaps I need to create something discretely to handle this outside of the ggplot function, if so then I'm completely at a loss.

Comment: `..level..` is calculated for `stat_density_2d` and `stat_contour`, whereas `..density..` is calculated for `stat_bin`. Not sure why they have 2 different names exactly. Maybe try `geom_bin_2d` or `geom_hex` and see if one of those is more what you're after

Comment: I will try this, many thanks.

Comment: trying the following:  my.data <- data.frame(x = (sample((1:10),10)), y = (sample((1:10),10)), z = (sample(c(rep(-1,70),rep(1,30)))))  ggplot(data = my.data, aes(x = x, y = y, z = z)) + xlim(-5, 15) + ylim(-5, 15) + geom_point(data = my.data, aes(colour = z))   but not doing what I want - I'm hoping to see the colour reflect the overall bias of the Y and N (1, -1) answers in the z data.